# Forward Slash Removal and Redirect Rules Interfering

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have two redirect rules that might be interfering

The first rule takes `domain.com/star/name-here` and uses `domain.com/star.php?view=name-here` and displays the data at `domain.com/star/name-here`

The name-here is what's pulling the data form the database to build the page.

The next rule removes all forward slashes from the end of urls for SEO reasons.

The problem happens when `domain.com/star/name-here/` is entered, the data is still displayed but the URL ends up as `domain.com/star/name-here?view=name-here/`

Can these rules coexist?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule   ^star/(.+)$   star.php?view=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can use that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^star/(.+)/?$ star.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the redirect **first**, and you need to make sure you're not redirecting requests for directories, otherwise mod_dir will cause a redirect loop:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^star/(.+)$ star.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
```

also, a good thing to do here is to make sure multiviews is turned off.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon Lin your solution worked. Now to add the remove .php extensions!

Also, for anyone else who might be working with this, you constantly have to clear the history when testing these. All the old problems were still happening until I wiped all my history.